# Density plot of 5 dimensional data

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstan

I fitted a Bayesian model (the model has 5 parameters) to time-series data. Then I extracted sets of 2000 parameter from the posterior and put them in a matrix. I want to plot the multivariate posterior density. How can I do that? I could not install "rgl" in R. But can I do this using package "ggplot"?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but you cannot plot a higher-dimension density distribution directly. You can only plot projections into a one- or two-parameter space.

Comment: @Roland, okay. :(